# Find two random variables X and Y such that E(XY) does not equal E(X)E(Y)?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

This is from a review for my exam tomorrow. From what I understand E(XY) = E(X)E(Y) if X and Y are continuous and independent. How do I find such two variables that are not independent? Im stuck here, please help! Thanks

Comment: In your second sentence: why "continuous"? Independence is sufficient.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb I think it's a different question. The question here is "can I find two non-independent variables satisfying this" whild the one you link two asks for two variables not satisfying the identity.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I was not reading carefully... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try pretty much any random variable $X$ and then take $Y = X.$ For ease of showing $E(X^2)\ne (E(X))^2$ take $X$ to be symmetric so that $E(X)=0$. For instance, let $X$ be a standard normal or even a two-valued random variable that takes value $-1$ with probability $1/2$ and $+1$ with probability $1/2.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $E \subseteq \Omega$ be measurable, and let $X$ be the indicator on $E$, and $Y$ the indicator on $E^{\complement}$. Then $XY \equiv 0$, but $E(X)E(Y) = \operatorname{Pr}(E) (1 - \operatorname{Pr}(E))$.